# XAMPP will connect to splash page but no other links are working

Tags: xampp, localhost, localserver

My xampp used to work fine, but i havent used it in a while and now it seems to have stopped working.
It says my apache and mysql are running fine in the XAMPP control panel, and when i type in 127.0.0.1 it takes me to the xampp splash page at 127.0.0.1/xampp.

However when i try to open the index page saying "it works!" at the directory localhost/xampp/htdocs/index.html it says object not found.

I get the same error message for all resources i try to display via my localhost.

This is the error log that was generated.

[Tue Sep 18 13:06:13 2012] [error] [client ::1] File does not exist: C:/xampp/htdocs/xampp/htdocs
[Tue Sep 18 13:06:17 2012] [error] [client ::1] File does not exist: C:/xampp/htdocs/crossdomain.xml, referer: "http://localhost/xampp/htdocs/index.html"

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case anyone else has this problem, i've solved it. When i typed localhost, by default it took me to localhost/xampp. I naturally assumed that my url address would be the same as my system directory, with localhost taking place of C, as in localhost/xampp/htdocs/etc... But apparently Localhost directory itself is htdocs... so i fixed the problem by typing localhost/index.html. Most of you already know this but i hope it may help someone else. –

Answer (score 0):

My problem solved by giving permission

```
sudo chmod 777 /Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/xampp/lang.tmp
```